# Односвязный список. Java .Длина списка

Tags: java

Помогите пожалуйста написать метод определяющий длину односвязного списка.
Задание:
Разработать класс-библиотеку для работы с односвязными списками. А именно 3 метода:

```
public class SingleLLUtils_1 {

public static int length(Node tail) {...}

public static int max(Node tail) {...}

public static int sum(Node tail) {...}

 }
```

Мой код вот:

```
public class SingleLLUtils_1 {

public static Node create (int value){
    if (value >=0 ){
        return new Node(value, create(value - 1));
    }else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static int length(Node tail) {
    return tail > 0 ?  length(tail-1) int count++  :  count;

}
}
```

Comment: Огласите код всего списка, пожалуйста.

Comment: @post_zeew  public static Node create (int value){
  if (value >=0 ){
   return new Node(value, create(value - 1));
  }else {
   return null;
  }
 }

Comment: Добавьте код всего списка в сам вопрос (его можно отредактировать).

Comment: @post_zeew добавил))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добрый вечер, господа!
Писал похожее задание.
В моем случае метод получения длины односвязного списка выглядел вот так:

В итоге, возвращается кол-во элементов всего списка. Если есть необходимость могу поделиться своим кодом.

`head` - начальный элемент списка, `head.next` - ссылка на следующий элемент.

```
public int getSize(){
    int count = 0;
    if(head != null){
        count++;
        while(head.nextN != null){
            count++;
            head = head.nextN;
        }
        }else{
            return 0;    
        }
    return count;
}
```

Полный код примера:

```
/*
Pr9-2*
Разработать класс для работы с односвязными списками.
4 метода из DynamicArray являются обязательными:

public class DynamicArray {
public Node add(int elem) {...}
public Node remove() {...}
public Node add(int index, int elem) {...}
public Node remove(int index) {...}
}

*/
package pr9.pkg2;

class Node{  
public int index;
public Node nextN;
}

class Container{
private Node head;
private Node tail;
public int getSize(){
    int count = 0;
    if(head != null){
        count++;
        while(head.nextN != null){
            count++;
            head = head.nextN;
        }
        }else{
            return 0;    
        }
    return count;
}

public void printContainer(){
    Node n = head;
        while(n!=null){
            System.out.print(n.index+" ");
            n = n.nextN;
        }
        System.out.println("");
}

public void addFirst(int element){
    Node n = new Node();
    n.index = element;
        if(head == null){
            head = n;
            tail = n;
        }else{
            n.nextN = head;
            head = n;
        }
}

public void addLast(int element){
    Node n = new Node();
    n.index = element;
        if(tail == null){
            head = n;
            tail = n;      
        }else{
            tail.nextN = n;
            tail = n;
        }
}

public void addMidle(int element, int index){
    Node n = head;
    Node n1 = new Node();
    n1.index = element;
        while(n.nextN != null){
            if(n.index == index){
                n1.nextN = n.nextN;
                n.nextN = n1;
                return;
            }
            n = n.nextN;
        }
}

public void setNodeIndex(int element, int index){
    if(head == null){
        System.out.println("Список пуст!");
        return;
    }
    if(head.index == index){
        head.index = element;
        return;
    }
    if(tail.index == index){
        tail.index = element;
        return;
    }
    Node n = head.nextN;
    while(n != null){
        if(n.index == index){
            n.index = element;
            return;
        }
        n = n.nextN;
    }


}

public void removeFirstNode(){
    if(head == null){
        System.out.println("Список пуст!");
    }else
        head = head.nextN;
}

public void removeNode(int index){
    if(head == null){
        System.out.println("Список пуст");
        return;
    }
    if(head == tail){
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        return;
    }
    if(head.index == index){
        head = head.nextN;
        return;
    }
    Node n = head;
        while(n.nextN != null){
            if(n.nextN.index == index){
                if(tail == n.nextN){
                    tail = n;
                }
                n.nextN = n.nextN.nextN;
                return;
            }
            n = n.nextN;
        }
}

}

public class Pr92 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container c = new Container();
        c.addFirst(1);
        c.addLast(2);
        c.addFirst(5);
        c.addLast(7);
        c.addMidle(8, 2);
        c.printContainer();
        c.setNodeIndex(77, 2);
        c.printContainer();
        c.addFirst(55);
        System.out.println(c.getSize());
    }
}
```

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, почему public Node nextN; - это ссылка на следующий ,  private Node head;
private Node tail;  - а это ссылка на голову и хвост , чем они отличаются?я не понимаю почему одна ссылка это следующий а другие пусть и приват, текущие ссылки ?хоть и то и то объекты класса нод, возможно из-за местоположения , всё равно поясните.

Comment: public Node nextN; -поле класса, которое содержит ссылку на объект своего типа.
Это поле необходимо для поддержания связи между элементами списка(указывать на следующий).
private Node head, tail; - поля другого класса: Container. Являются экземплярами класса Node и указывают на первый и последний элементы списка. А приватные они потому, что закрыты(инкапсулированные) и возможность работы с ними предоставляется методами.
Отсюда следует, что типы у полей одинаковые потому, что они являются объектами одного класса, но их функция разная в зависимости от того в каком классе они используются.